# push react native does not unsubscribe when useEffect dependency changes

Tags: javascript, react-native, pusher

I'm using pusher (react native) to receive events. I have placed the pusher code in a useEffect with a cleanup function. When the dependency of the useEffect-function changes, the user should be disconnected and then reconnected again.

My (simplified) code:

```
import React, {useEffect, createContext} from 'react';
import {Pusher} from '@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native';

export const PusherContext = createContext();

const pusher = Pusher.getInstance();

export const PusherProvider = ({children}) => {
  const socket = async () => {
    console.log('connect & subscribe');

    await pusher.init({
      apiKey: 'api-key-here',
      cluster: 'eu',
    });
    await pusher.connect();
    await pusher.subscribe({
      channelName: 'channel-name',
      onEvent: event => {
        console.log('event called');
      },
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket();

    return async () => {
      console.log('unsubscribe & disconnect');
      await pusher.unsubscribe({channelName: 'channel-name'});
      await pusher.disconnect();
    };
  }, [dependency]);

  return <PusherContext.Provider value={{}}>{children}</PusherContext.Provider>;
};
```

What happens? At first it's ok, when I receive and event I get a console.log('event called'); only once. But when the dependency changes, it seems that the user is not disconnected at all but a second time connected, because after that, I get the console.log 2 times. Whenever the dependency in the useEffect-function changes, it counts up. I'm storing events in redux and I want to store every event only once. Some events have the same payload.

When I the dependency changes, the console.log('unsubscribe & disconnect') is printed so the cleanup function is called but it seems like it doesn't unsubscribe and/or disconnect.

Is this possibly a known error, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I know that providing `useEffect` an  async callback could have undesirable results. Maybe the same logic applies to the cleanup function? I skimmed the docs but I didnt find saying you shouldnt but it might be worth a shot

Comment: I found this comment https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native/issues/65 with the same problem, but they say it should be fixed in 1.2.0. I'm using 1.2.1 (and I've tested 1.2.0).

Comment: Do you have to use pusher websocket? React native has built in [web socket support](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#websocket-support)

Answer (score 0):

Privae Channel not even subscribe in private-

onSubscriptionSucceeded:

(channelName, data) => {

```
      console.log(`Subscribed to ${channelName}`);
      // console.log(`I can now access me: ${myChannel.me}`);
      // console.log(`And here are the channel members: ${myChannel.members}`);
      const channel = pusher.getChannel(channelName);

      
    },
```