# Pusher channel in React Native + Redux does not use updated state

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo

I'm using [pusher-websocket-react-native](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native) to create a real-time chat for a mobile application on [Expo](https://expo.dev/).

I noticed that whenever I subscribe to a presence channel, it maintains its own state which means that when a state change occurs in Redux store, the channel's onEvent does not use the latest value.

```js
const {
  selectedChatRoom, // <--- When a state change occurs here...
  // ...
} = useSelector(state => state.chat, shallowEqual);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(selectedChatRoom); // <--- This one uses new value
}, [selectedChatRoom]}

// ...

const onEvent = (event) => {
  switch (event.eventName) {
    case bindingKeys.chat.message:
      onMessageReceived(event);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};

const onMessageReceived = (event) => {
  // ...
  const chatRoomId = event.data.chatRoomId;
  const isChatRoomOpen = selectedChatRoom?._id === chatRoomId; // <--- This one maintains old value
  // ...
};
```

Currently, I'm handling this issue by unsubscribing and then subscribing again (based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244678/push-react-native-does-not-unsubscribe-when-useeffect-dependency-changes), but there is no unbind and bind for Pusher in React Native) to update the state but I don't think this is a good solution. Does anyone know of any other solution I could try? There does not seem to be many reference on this issue for React Native.

```js
// Current solution
const resubscribeToChannels = async () => {
  if (selectedChatRoom?._id === undefined) return;
  await pusher
    .unsubscribe({
      channelName: `presence-${selectedChatRoom?._id}`,
    })
    .then(async () => {
      await pusher.subscribe({
        channelName: `presence-${selectedChatRoom?._id}`,
        onEvent, // <--- I believe this rebinds the event to the current state 
                 //      but will maintain this state until another re-subscription
      });
    }
  );
};

useEffect(() => {
  resubscribeToChannels();
}, [selectedChatRoom]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get the state variable directly from the redux store. It is probably not the best option and I do not recommend it, but if you are out of options you might consider:

In your main "index" file or where you set/define the redux store

```
export const store = configureStore(.....);
```

In you component

```
import {store} from "../index";

const callback = () => {
    const my_variable = store.getState().your_variable;
}
```

This way you will always get the latest value.

Not sure if you can do it in RN, though.